# Ruby on Rails Application Connecting to Multiple APIs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I am developing a Ruby on Rails application to connect to multiple APIs. Therefore, the user can go to my Web App and select the API that they want to use with their device.
I was searching on the web, and I could not find a good Rails Architecture to do it, I thought about using microservices which I think it would be useful as you could create a microservice for each of the APIs. As I am new using multiple APIs in Rails I do not have a well-formed image of how the software achitecture would look like.

Can someone help me out with it?

Answer (score 0):

You are connecting multiple api's, are these api's you are going to create or actual services that exist? If they already exist and you just want to pull in the information there would be no need for microservices architecture.

I would just create a service object for each api that would then be called on some action or function in your api.

Comment: Yeah I will be using api’s from different providers. I will check on creating a service object for each of them. Thanks for the help

Comment: Yeah I like the structure around using service objects as you can create a good class hierarchy around each provider and specific services for each action inheriting from a base class that would provide the authentication.

Comment: whenever I finish the project I let you know how it looks like. Thanks again

Comment: @RafaelCavagnoli have you ever finished the project? I would be curious to learn more about the architecture you used.

Comment: @TomHert Yes of course, feel free to send me over any questions you would like